# How to make web filter support async?

Tags: servlet-filters, resteasy, embedded-jetty

I am using RESTEasy async support. However it breaks my JSONPfilter.

```
public class JSONPFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSONPFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String callbackName = request.getParameter("callback");

        if (callbackName != null) {

            ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
            sos.print(callbackName + "(");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            sos.print(");");
        } else {

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }


curl http://localhost:8088/v0/chat?callback=jsonp
jsonp();{"data":"hello world: 53","timestamp":"2012-11-26T05:04:26.000Z"}
```

The correct result should be:

```
jsonp({"data":"hello world: 53","timestamp":"2012-11-26T05:04:26.000Z"});
```

The filter works fine on non-async servlet.
I have tried adding @WebFilter

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class JSONPFilter implements Filter {
```

But it seems like the server doesn't recognize @WebFilter, because once I removed the entry in web.xml, the filter didn't work at all.

I have tried adding

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

No luck so far.

By the way I am using embedded Jetty v8.13